# Get mouse position at all times when dragging

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, position, mouse, drag

I want to get the mouse position when the mouse moves while dragging.

Here is my minimal not working example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas x:Name="_canvas" Background="Green">
        <TextBlock x:Name="_positionTextBlock"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="_dragSource"
                   Width="20"
                   Height="50"
                   Fill="Blue" 
                   Canvas.Top="150" 
                   Canvas.Left="20" 
                   PreviewMouseDown="DoDrag"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="_dragTarget"
                   Width="60" 
                   Height="70"
                   Fill="Red" 
                   Canvas.Top="110" 
                   Canvas.Left="300" 
                   AllowDrop="True"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DoDrag(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dragSource, "abc", DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see: I have a `TextBlock` called `_positionTextBlock` which should display the current mouse position while dragging.

**Edit** (long story): I have a green rectanlge that can be dragged and droped on the red rectangle. My requirement is, to display the mouse position while dragging the green rectangle.

How do I do that?

What I have tried:

changing the constructor of `MainWindow` to:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DragOver += (s, e) => _positionTextBlock.Text = e.GetPosition(_canvas).ToString();
}
```

But this only shows the position when the mouse is over the red rectangle.

I also tried:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MouseMove += (s, e) => _positionTextBlock.Text = e.GetPosition(_canvas).ToString();
}
```

but the `MouseMove`-Event doesn't fire while dragging

I also tried:

```
private void DoDrag(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs ev)
{
    _dragSource.GiveFeedback +=
        (s, e) => _positionTextBlock.Text = Mouse.PrimaryDevice.GetPosition(_canvas).ToString();
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dragSource, "abc", DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

but this seems to get the window-position in screen coordinates.

And this is where I got stuck. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try QueryContinueDrag event.

Comment: I tried, but is has, like `GiveFeedback` event, no `GetPosition()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your demo, and found that if you set `AllowDrop="True"` on the window, the `DragOver` event works.

If you want to avoid dropping to the window, you can listen the PreviewDragOver event of window. Then set the `DragEventArgs.Effect` to None and `DragEventArgs.Handled` to True.

You can also get the mouse position by another way, which works all the time, expect you need a timer to refresh the position regularly.

`Visual.PointFromScreen(MousePositionToScreen);`

```
public Point MousePositionToScreen
{
    get
    {
        GetCursorPos(out POINT p);
        return new Point(p.X, p.Y);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT pt);
```

Finally, you can try [Keith Stein's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404366/wpf-track-mouse-during-drag-drop-while-allowdrop-false). It's much more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited using PreviewMouseMove**

**Second edit: Full sample**

XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="_canvas" Background="Green">
    <TextBlock x:Name="_positionTextBlock"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="_dragSource"
               Width="20"
               Height="50"
               Fill="Blue" 
               Canvas.Top="150" 
               Canvas.Left="20" 
               PreviewMouseMove="DragSourcePreviewMouseMove"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="_dragTarget"
               Width="60" 
               Height="70"
               Fill="Red" 
               Canvas.Top="110" 
               Canvas.Left="300" 
               AllowDrop="True"/>
</Canvas>
```

Codebehind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void DragSourcePreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        _positionTextBlock.Text = e.GetPosition(_canvas).ToString();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: why should that work? you have added an `if` inside the event handler. But the problem was, that the event doesn't fire. Thus the event handler didn't get called! (disregarding the fact, that this doesn't compile...)

Comment: @Rico-E I edited it to use PreviewMouseMove, it works for me. Also remember to mark the event as handled.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The `PreviewMouseMove`-event doesn't get fired, so the handler never gets called.

Comment: Strange, i verified it myself using your own xaml and it works. I only removed the 'PreviewMouseDown="DoDrag"'. (In fact you can remove both rectangles for the test). Post the code you tested.

Comment: You removed the `PreviewMouseDown="DoDrag"``? Are you kidding me? That is the most important part! I want to get the mouse position **while dragging**!

Comment: The sample code i posted affects the whole window (like your solutions) not only the first rectangle. It was for test purposses, thats why i removed it. If you want it to work only inside the green rectangle use that 'PreviewMouseDown' event with the same code behind but for the rectangle instead.

Comment: @Rico-E I Added the full solution